# Why is xeditable PUTting to edit action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, x-editable

I'm using the `bootstrap-sass` and `x-editable-rails` gems in my rails application.

I have the following line in my `show.html.haml`:

```
= editable @article, :title
```

It's generating html that looks like:

```
<span class="editable editable-click" title="Title" data-type="text" data-model="article" data-name="title" data-value="another!!!!" data-placeholder="Title" data-url="/articles/3">another!!!!</span>
```

Why is it when the field is submitted that it's sending a PUT request to `/articles/3/edit` when the data-url is explicitly set to `/articles/3`?

How do I get it to PUT at `/articles/3`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

The field was correctly sending the request to `/articles/3`, which was being handled by the update action.  But then I had a redirect to the edit action, which I guess was causing the problem.  I'm not sure why it still ended up being a PUT request on the redirect.  In any case, the routes weren't set up to handle that.